# Account Id is not passing from Visualforce page to controller to display child object - this is useful to build a nested table as well

Tags: visualforce, controller, childrecords

Can anyone help me to get account id from Visualforce page to controller , here is my code

we can get id - i am editing it .

Vf Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="accsearchconroller" sidebar="false" readOnly="true" tabStyle="Account">
   <!--to reset/clear button - java script-->
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function resetForm(ele) {
                 $(ele).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
                return false;
          }
   </script>

  <apex:pageMessages id="msg" />
   <apex:form id="formid">  

      <center><B>
      <h5>  Account ID </h5>
      <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" label="Input" />
      <apex:commandButton value="Search Account" action="{!search}" />    
      <apex:commandButton value="Clear/Reset" onclick="return resetForm(this);" action="{!clear}" rerender="pbtable" immediate="true"/>  </B>
      </center>
      <h5 style="text-align:right;color:black;">
     <apex:outputText >  Please Enter full name/exact Id of the account for narrowing your search results </apex:outputText> </h5>
  <!--Page block starts-->

   <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results" id="pageblock1" >  
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a" rendered="{!acc.size!=null}" id="pbtable1">
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!a.Id}" id="acctId">  
    <apex:param name="acctId" value="{!a.Id}"/>
    </apex:inputHidden>     
    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" >  
      <apex:outputlink value="/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>  
     </apex:column>  
     <apex:column headerValue="Owner" value="{!a.owner.name}"/>  
     <apex:column headerValue="RecordType Name" value="{!a.recordtype.name}" />
     </apex:pageBlockTable>     
    </apex:pageBlock>  

 <apex:pageBlock title="Account - Faces" id="pageblock2">
  <apex:commandButton value="Diaplsy Faces" action="{!getallfac}"/>
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!allfaces}" var="f" rendered="{!allfaces.size!=null}" id="pbtable2">   
    <apex:column headerValue="Facility Name" >  
      <apex:outputlink value="/{!f.id}">{!f.Name}</apex:outputlink>  
     </apex:column>          
    </apex:pageBlockTable>     
   </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And My Controller :

```
public with sharing class accsearchconroller {

    transient public list <account> acc {get;set;}  
    public string searchstring {get;set;}  
    transient List<Account> AllAccountRecs = new List<Account>();
    public List<Facility__c> allfacilities = new list<Facility__c>();

  //constructor do nothing for now 
   public accsearchconroller() {

    }              
    //Searching method with string
    public void search(){ 
    if (searchstring == null || searchstring.length()==0) {
    ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please Enter the account Id to Search' );
      ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

      }else if(searchstring != null && searchstring.length()<=4) {
          ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Search text should have atleast 5 characters' );
      ApexPages.addmessage(msg);
             }

       else if(searchstring != null && searchstring.length()>4){
       string bid='Residual';
      string searchquery='select name,id,owner.name,recordtype.name from account where name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\''; 
      accid=[SELECT Id from Account where condition].Id;
      acc= Database.query(searchquery);     

      } 
   }     
   public void clear(){
     if(acc.size()!=0){
       acc = null;
   }
   }  
   //   for facility deisplay
      public void getallfac(){     
         String aId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('acctId');     
     system.debug('***********************************************'+aId);    
         if(aId == null){            
           // return null;
         }
         else{
         allfaces = [select Id,Name From Facility__c where Account__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('acctId')];}
         //return allfacilities;
     }   

}
```

Comment: Please can you post only relevant code ? It is very hard to find useful informations with your code !

Comment: Also it would be very helpful if you would explain the situation in a few sentences: what works? what does not? Any errors?

Comment: public void getallfac(){    - this method i am not able to pass account id here

Comment: From this VF Page basically , I need account Id which i am displaying and pass the same account id to getallfac() method to display that related records

Comment: got the answer and it works fine ..thanks all  and the answer as : accid=[SELECT Id from Account where condition].Id;

Comment: @sfdev - can you post this as an answer and mark it accepted so the question does not keep popping to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accid=[SELECT Id from Account where condition].Id;

Comment: Although this does answer your own question which is great, can please you provide a touch  more detail to help future readers understand your answer.

Comment: sure , i will do , i am not able to accept the answer it says you can make it as accepted after 17 hours , will edit tomorrow and update. thanks guys.

Comment: edited and added that line in the above code